# Как с помощью регулярного выражения вывести нужное значение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Строка вида - https://github.com/user-project/repository/releases

Нужно вывести - user/repository

User и Repository каждый раз разные.

Я сделал так:

```
$githubname = substr($row['github'],19);//срезаем домен
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]*[-]?[a-zA-Z]*\/[a-zA-Z]*/', $githubname, $githubname);//выводим user и repository
echo $githubname[0];
```

Хотелось бы без substr, а только регулярное выражение

Comment: Может, лучше [`explode('/', parse_url($row['github'], PHP_URL_PATH))`](https://ideone.com/0jhVwu)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user может содержать числа.
Реальный репо https://github.com/1016135097/weChat_wangyang
Свои "пять копеек"

```
re = '/\.com\/(.+)\/(.+)\//U';
$str = 'https://github.com/user-project/repository/releases';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

https://regex101.com/r/wL8RKj/1

Comment: Отличный ответ учитывающий все обстоятельства!

Answer (score 0):

можно и так, [ссылка на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/q1KpxD/1)

> github.com/(?[A-Za-z-/]+)/